# How do I customise MS Word 'manage sources' (creating reference lists) to do what I want it to do?

Tags: microsoft-word, bibliography

I am using the **manage sources** facility in Microsoft Word to create a reference list/bibliography (Harvard style). It's a substantial document with around 350 references but I am experiencing a number of problems such as:

1. I cannot include italics for species names
2. The automatic bibliography insertion will only include the first initial of each
   author (which is not always the one they are most commonly known by)
3. How do I get the bibliography to include the DOI? (and other fields
   of my choosing)
4. When inserting citations, Word includes the full list of corporate authors, which may sometimes be extremely long. How do I reduce this to 'XXX et al'?

Apologies that this seems like 4 different questions but I will be grateful for any pointers at all on how to use **manage sources** more productively. I have googled this but the answers that come up only deal with basic stuff on how to add a reference. I can't find anything that offers more detailed help.

Comment: You will have the easiest time if you use a third-party Add-in like Mendeley. Word's bibliography styles are, for the most part, long out of date. There is no reason to think that they will be updated in the foreseeable future. Look on the **Microsoft Community** https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word for information about APA 7 to get a better feel for the magnitude of this issue. Especially look at responses by Rohn who tends to provide lots of links.

Comment: @CharlesKenyon Thank you, very useful information. Unfortunately no good for the current document I'm working on (I didn't write it) but certainly something to recommend in the future.

Comment: If you are basically stuck with using Microsoft's built-in mechanism, your best bet is probably to look at the style mechanism created by Yves Dhondt and currently available from https://github.com/codingo/BibWord . If you investigated the links as suggested by @CharlesKenyon you may already have found them. There is an explanatory document there which you should skim, partly because it may indicate how to deal with your (2), (4) and possibly even (3), and there are .XSLT s for a few variations on the Harvard style...

Comment: ...You may even find that someone in the same general area of research has created their own .XSL based on that (although I would guess many are using LaTeX mechanisms). What you probably won't get in there is something to help you format parts of titles or other fields  using, e.g. italics. Unfortunately that is not easily achieved within the Microsoft mechanism because you are stuck with XSLT v1, which makes this a much more difficult task than v2. I have seen one attempt to create XSLT code to do that but think it would be very difficult to integrate.